# SimpleJdbcCall ignoring JdbcTemplate fetch size

Tags: java, database, spring, stored-procedures, jdbc

We are calling the pl/sql stored procedure through Spring SimpleJdbcCall, the fetchsize set on the JdbcTemplate is being ignored by SimpleJdbcCall. The rowmapper resultset fetch size is set to 10 even though we have set the jdbctemplate fetchsize to 200. Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Have printed the fetchsize of resultset in the rowmapper in the below code snippet - Once it is 200 and  other time it is 10 even though I use the same JdbcTemplate on both occassion.

This direct execution through jdbctemplate returns fetchsize of 200 in the row mapper

```
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
    jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(200);

    List temp = jdbcTemplate.query("select 1 from dual", new ParameterizedRowMapper() {
        public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            System.out.println("Direct template : " + resultSet.getFetchSize());
            return new String(resultSet.getString(1));
        }
    });
```

This execution through SimpleJdbcCall is always returning fetchsize of 10 in the rowmapper

```
jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withSchemaName(schemaName)
                .withCatalogName(catalogName).withProcedureName(functionName);
jdbcCall.returningResultSet((String) outItValues.next(), new        ParameterizedRowMapper<Map<String, Object>>() {
                public Map<String, Object> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
                   System.out.println("Through simplejdbccall " + rs.getFetchSize());
                    return extractRS(rs, row);
                }
            });
outputList = (List<Map<String, Object>>) jdbcCall.executeObject(List.class, inParam);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how much the `getFetchSize()` method on `ResultSet` can be trusted. `JdbcTemplate` calls `setFetchSize()` on the `Statement`, and assumes the JDBC driver will do the right thing with it, including propagating it to all `ResultSet` objects. It seems that the Oracle JDBC driver isn't, in this case.

The reason you get different behaviour from the two approaches is that executing a simple `SELECT` through `JdbcTemplate` is simple JDBC, whereas the `ResultSet` you get back from `SimpleJdbcCall` is obtained as an OUT parameter to the call. The latter is more complex, and it seems the information is being lost.

As a workaround, have you tried calling `ResultSet.setFetchSize()` yourself? It might not work, but it's worth a go.  You could also submit a issue to http://jira.springsource.org/ to see if they think that Spring's JDBC layer could address it transparently.

Comment: Setting the fetch size of the ResultSet in the mapRow method of the RowMapper class worked a treat for me.  Thanks man!

Comment: mapRow is called for each row in resultset, it is not the right place. Fetch size should be set before calling rs.next()

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit the number of rows returning with Oracle, you should use a subselect query and specify the start and stop rownumber like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROWNUM as id, demo.* FROM DEMO_TABLE demo)
WHERE id >= startRowNumber AND id <= stopRowNumber;
```

If you don't want any Oracle specific code, you should consider JPA instead of JDBC:

```
Query selectQuery = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
selectQuery.setMaxResults(maxNumberOfElements);
selectQuery.setFirstResult(startRowNumber);
List demoList = entityManager.getResultList(queryString);
```

Comment: SimpleJdbcCall is for calling stored procs and functions and the client has no visibility to the  sql.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but a helpful thing I think. When you create objects of spring classes by hand most people tend to forget calling the afterPropertiesSet() method (which is called by Spring to perform any initialisation).

I checked the jdbcTemplate.afterPropertiesSet() it only seems to set the exception translator and the data source.