# How to improve performance of retrieving a REF CURSOR into Java using Spring?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring

I am performing a call to a function which is part of a DB package.  This package is deployed in two locations.  One local and another remote (across the Atlantic).

I am retrieving the data via the Spring JDBC template.

There is one function which returns approximately 1000 rows (not all that much) and this is taking about 1.5 seconds when getting the data locally but it's taking in the region of 12 seconds when getting the data remotely.

In all sample code, names have been changed and code has been simplified a little.

Please see an example of the current Java code:

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(getDataSource())
                                            .withSchemaName(MY_SCHEMA_NAME)
                                            .withCatalogName("REFCURSOR_PKG")
                                            .withFunctionName("GET_DATA")
                                            .returningResultSet("RESULT_SET", new DataEntryMapper());

        SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                                    .addValue("the_name", name)
                                    .addValue("the_rev", rev);

        Map resultSet = simpleJdbcCall.execute(params);
        ArrayList list = (ArrayList) resultSet.get("RESULT_SET");
```

The RowMapper class looks something like this:

```
class RouteDataEntryMapper implements RowMapper {
        public RouteDataEntry mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return new DataEntry(resultSet.getString("name"), 
                                    Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("rev"));
        }
    }
```

SQL package spec snippet:

```
TYPE REF_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
```

SQL function:

```
 FUNCTION GET_ROUTE_DATA(the_name VARCHAR2, the_rev VARCHAR2) RETURN REF_CURSOR AS

  RESULT_SET REF_CURSOR;

  BEGIN
    OPEN RESULT_SET FOR
    select *
    from table_name tn
    where tn.name = the_name
    and tn.rev = the_rev;

    RETURN RESULT_SET;

    CLOSE RESULT_SET;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE;

  END GET_ROUTE_DATA;
```

I have tried using regular boiler plate JDBC also (create connection, prepare statement, execute statement, retrieve data from RESULT_SET, etc) and I found that the vast majority of time was spent looping over the RESULT_SET and extracting the data out of it and into some pojos.  In the case of the Spring code above, most of the time was spent during the execute() method but this is probably because it creates the objects using the RowMapper at that time.

So, the common area between them is the performing of actions such as:

```
rs.getString("name")
```

and I'm guessing that this is where the problem lies but I could be wrong.

As I said, locally the delay is fine but remotely it's taking way too long.  Is this because it's going to the DB on every rs.get... ?  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the fetch size of your `Statement` and/or `ResultSet`?  Have you tried increasing the fetch size?

Comment: Have you been able to compare the speed versus running the same SQL query without the PL/SQL wrapper? Is it the REF_CURSOR that brings additional slowness, or is it actually retrieving the query results that is slow? Also, what are the column types in the response set; if there are any LONG/*LOB -columns, they will cause separate server round-trips (even if you fetch a CLOB with rs.getString()).

Comment: The fetch size was the problem. I added some logging statements and discovered that every 10th resultSet.next() (using boiler plate JDBC method) was taking time (about 140 ms when cross site). I changed the fetch size to 1000 and this made it A LOT faster (first resultSet.next() takes about 550-600 ms but that's it and overall operation takes 1.5 seconds versus 12-14 seconds before). However, I'm now having trouble trying to work out how to set the fetch size using the Spring SimpleJdbcCalll but at least now I know what I need to do. Thanks @JustinCave!

Comment: Found solution to setting fetch size in Spring.  Just need to set the fetch size on the ResultSet object in the mapRow method of the RowMapper class. Found solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2407573/487812

Answer (score 2):

> rs.getString("name")

`ResultSet.get*(String columnName)` can be replaced with `ResultSet.get*(int columnNaumber)` which is slightly faster but I doubt that the main problem here.

> Is this because it's going to the DB on every rs.get... ?

While it really depends the driver I suspect it won't. For a cached result-set it might go to ther server when your scroll through the cursor but it would still fetch a bunch of rows in every roundtrip.

Two more suggestions I have are:

- Use a network sniffing utility to see the data being transferred
- Check your driver for any option to pre-fetch and such like.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It also helped me. Please see comment to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

add this line :-

```
.withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess
```

in the following code lines

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(getDataSource())
                                            .withSchemaName(MY_SCHEMA_NAME)
                                            .withCatalogName("REFCURSOR_PKG")
                                            .withFunctionName("GET_DATA")
                                            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess  // to avoid fetching meta data info from database
```